# Activity layout doesn't change when a fragment is added

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity which adds a full screen fragment when a button inside it is clicked.
This is the XML of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="clyky.cartracker.activities.AddVehicleActivity"
    android:id="@+id/addVehicleContainer">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lblPlate"
            android:text="Targa"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtPlate"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtPlate"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Targa del veicolo"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lblKm"
            android:text="Chilometri"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtPlate"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtKm"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Chilometraggio"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblInUse"
            android:labelFor="@+id/chckbxInUse"
            android:text="In uso:"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chckbxInUse"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblInsuranceDate"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtInsuranceDate"
            android:text="Data di assicurazione:"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtInsuranceDate"
            android:text=""/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnShowDatePickerForInsuranceDate"
            android:onClick="showDatePicker"
            android:text="Seleziona"
            android:tag="0"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblMatriculationDate"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtMatriculationDate"
            android:text="Data d'immatricolazione:"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtMatriculationDate"
            android:text=""/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnShowDatePickerForMatriculationDate"
            android:onClick="showDatePicker"
            android:text="Seleziona"
            android:tag="1"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblEffectiveFuelEconomy"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtEffectiveFuelEconomy"
            android:text="Consumo di carburante (km/l):"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtEffectiveFuelEconomy"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblMake"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtLastInspectionDate"
            android:text="Produttore:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spnrMake"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblModel"
            android:labelFor="@+id/spnrModel"
            android:text="Modello:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spnrModel"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblTrim"
            android:labelFor="@+id/spnrTrim"
            android:text="Assetto:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spnrTrim"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnShowInspectionDates"
            android:text="Aggiungi date di revisione"
            android:onClick="showInspectionDatesFragment"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:onClick="submit"
            android:text="Invia"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

this is the method which changes the fragment when `btnShowInspectionDates` is clicked:

```
public void showInspectionDatesFragment(View v)
{
    InspectionDatesFragment f = InspectionDatesFragment.newInstance(null);
    Utilities.addFragment(R.id.addVehicleContainer, f, null, getSupportFragmentManager());
}
```

`Utilities.addFragment` simply performs the fragment transaction (it creates a `FragmentTransaction` object, calls `add` method on it and executes the commit of the transaction).

This is the layout of my `InspectionDatesFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/recycler_view_fragment_layout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddInspectionDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`recycler_view_fragment_layout` simply contains a `RecyclerView` inside a `LinearLayout`, I use this as base layout in others layout which contains a `RecyclerView`.

So, when I click on `btnShowInspectionDates` the layout on my phone doesn't seem to change. I've used the debugger to check if my fragment is really created by putting a breakpoint in `onCreatedView`, and yes, it's created successfully because it doesn't throw any exception. 
logcat doesn't seem to give useful things, so does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Now, I've created a fragment which contains the previous layout of my `AddVehicleActivity`, and then I change the two fragment when `btnShowInspectionDates` is clicked. But now I've got another problem: `btnAddInspectionDate` isn't shown in my `InspectionDatesFragment`: the view is totally white.

inspection_dates_fragment_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/recycler_view_fragment_layout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddInspectionDate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="+"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding it in wrong container.

In activity layout, just keep container for fragments.

Create one more fragment, that will have layout which activity is having currently and add it in activity's fragment container.

On button click, just replace/add fragment you want to launch.